# How to render an already rendered after effect template?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, template

I have downloaded a ready made template for After Effects. I edited it, added 
text and images of my own.  When i put it for rendering I didn't find 
the h264 format.

Without bothering much I rendered this 36 seconds long clip and the outcome was a 25GB file! It took aeons to render, almost 1 hour.

Is there any way to render a pre-rendered After Effects template?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Adobe Media Encoder brother. Install the AME, should be the same version of your After Effects. I installed a 2020 AME when I was using a 2019 AE and got some problems with it, so yeah, install it with the same version of AE.

So under Composition choose Add to Adobe Media Encoder Queue.

That should fix your problem of h. 264

Comment: Thank you so much. it helped.